# Using regex_replace on bracketed expression

Tags: regex, c++11, wolfram-mathematica, maple

Gal: a small c++ program to convert maple output to valid mathematica input.

The problem: bracketed expressions as the following example:
sin(-1/(-1+x)/x) should become sin[-1/(-1+x)/x]

As you can see, the only the brackets for the sin function itself should be replaced. Is there a way to do so without touching the inner content of the brackets, using regex_replace()? I was unable to come up with it myself.

The actual input will be much longer expressions, with files up to several kb in size. Hence the need for an efficient conversion.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you can do that in a multitude of language. You should narrow your question to only one language, show what you have tried so far and why you have issue with your code

Comment: It's a real shame that the example has 2 expressions neither of which is correctly bracketed !

Comment: It seems he wants to use c++ as an intermediate processor. Quesion could use clarification. In any case see here  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/163184/2079  and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31804/2079

Answer (score 2):

If you have Maple output because you are generating it in Maple, then perhaps you can generate the desired output at the same time.

It's hard to make it more generally applicable to your wider goal with just the one brief example.

The use of single right-quotes and the 1-level `eval` calls are to prevent unwanted evaluation (eg. Maple would pull out the leading minus sign from the `sin` call otherwise).

```
ee := 'sin'(-1/(-1+x)/x):

lprint( eval(ee,1) );    
  sin(-1/(-1+x)/x)

ff := subsindets(eval(ee,1),specfunc(sin),u->'Sin'[op(u)]):

lprint( eval(ff,1) );                                      
  Sin[-1/(-1+x)/x]

sprintf("%a", eval(ff,1) );

           "Sin[-1/(-1+x)/x]"
```

Or, if your original is a string rather than an unevaluated function call,

```
restart;

s:="sin(-1/(-1+x)/x)";

        s := "sin(-1/(-1+x)/x)"

gg:=parse(s):

lprint( eval(gg,1) );
  sin(-1/(-1+x)/x)

ff := subsindets(eval(gg,1),specfunc(sin),u->'Sin'[op(u)]):

lprint( eval(ff,1) );
  Sin[-1/(-1+x)/x]

sprintf("%a", eval(ff,1) );

          "Sin[-1/(-1+x)/x]"
```